# Jmeter save test result in mongodb collection

Tags: mongodb, jmeter

I am executing a jmeter test from command line like below,

```
jmeter -n -t "D:\\apache-jmeter-4.0\\bin\\Test.jmx" -l result.jtl
```

This command starts the run and writes the result data to result.jtl as below,

```
2018/06/05 20:34:58.307,1917,Home Page,200,OK,Thread Group 1-9,text,true,138969,629
2018/06/05 20:34:58.278,2001,Home Page,200,OK,Thread Group 1-5,text,true,138969,658
......
```

I want the jmeter to redirect and save the test result in mongodb while test is running. Is it possible to achieve this ? I want to execute some custom checks & calculations on each row of result data while test is running. If it is possible, please suggest me how it can be achieved.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. Add the next lines to *user.properties* file

   ```
   not_in_menu=
   jmeter.save.saveservice.autoflush=true
   ```
2. Add [tearDown Thread Group](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#tearDown_Thread_Group) to your Test Plan
3. At this stage you have 2 options:

   - import your .jtl file into MongoDB using [`mongoimport` command](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongoimport/) from the [OS Process Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#OS_Process_Sampler)
   - Add [MongoDB Source Config](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#MongoDB_Source_Config_(DEPRECATED)) to the tearDown Thread Group and specify your connection details there and later on use [db.collection.insert()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.insert/) function add the data to MongoDB from the [JSR223 Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler), see [How to Load Test MongoDB with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/ja/blog/how-load-test-mongodb-jmeter) for more details if needed.

Comment: Hi @Dmitri, as per the jmeter link , "tearDown Thread Group" can be utilized to perform Post-Test Actions but i want the data on runtime white test is running. Please clarify this doubt.